# Print class attribute in format

Tags: python-2.7

I'd like to show an attribute of a class variable. How can I get the result in a pre-defined format?

I want to show the attribute in a formatted way without changing the attribute, similar to **repr** for printing a class instance?

```py
class Name(object):
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x

example = Name(3.1415)
example.x
```

Obviously, it will return 3.1415. But I want example.x to show 3.1 by default while its value is still 3.1415.  Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use print statement to do so

```
print("%.1f" % example.x)
```

**Update:** If you want to do it without print, I think the only other solution is to use a different variable.

```
class Name(object):
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x
        self.x_round = round(x,1)


example = Name(3.1415)
example.x_round
```

Comment: Thanks. I know i can do that way. But is there a way for example.x automatically show 3.1?

Comment: The only other way I can think of is to create a new variable and use it

Comment: Thanks. I found an elegant way is to introduce a separate function to print the format wanted. For example, introduce a pretty_format_print function, which can provide a defined way to print out a result every time when we want to show the result.

Comment: Wow. Glad you found that.